Error in Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration.targets file
I am facing below error in Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration.targets file while migrating from Xamarin Forms to .NET MAUI
The expression "[System.Version]::Parse('')" cannot be evaluated. Version string portion was too short or too long. (Parameter 'input')
enter image description here
I tried deleting bin & obj but no luck. Please help me with the solution.
Thanks ☺️

Check your *.csproj files for missing Version="*" for PackageReference please.
Are you using NuGet Central Package Management?
